# Centralizing slide with bxslider

Tags: jquery, slide, bxslider

I'm making a slide with this plugin, but I'm having trouble centering a slide ( https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4 ). 
The width will adjust according to the screen resolution, each slide has a specific (912px), width of the second slide is the default (startSlide: 1) would be centralized and a larger than 912px monitor the slide left and right would be appearing partially

Comment: Post some code. Show, what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

```
<ul class="bxslider" style="position: absolute; left:50%;   margin-left:-450px;">
```

and

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider( { startSlide: 1, minSlides: 2, maxSlides: 2, moveSlides: 1, hideControlOnEnd : true, pager:false, slideMargin : 5, responsive : true, slideWidth: 960, slideMargin: 500 });
```